# Technical-Support Tag usage

Tags: discussion, tags

I was trying to edit a question to include the tag for "technical-support" when someone had a question about setting up their laptop monitor for gaming:

[Using a laptop as the monitor for a console](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/37227/using-a-laptop-as-the-monitor-for-a-console)

The edit was rejected on the grounds of this:

> The technical-support tag should be used when there are problems involved with installing or running a game, or setting up a piece of hardware.

This is a bit confusing to me. Is the user not requesting how to "set up a piece of hardware"? They are requesting a step by step guide on how to use their piece of hardware to achieve this goal and it seemed relevant enough to me. Can someone shed any light on this? I'd rather not make the same mistake again.

Comment: Sorry about that; this is my fault. I was slightly confused about how the technical-support tag should be used.

Comment: @mana To be fair, it's also a bad question, for a host of other reasons.

Comment: @Mana +1 That's OK. I really appreciate that you're saying this. Is there a chance this can be rectified? Or do I need to resubmit?

Comment: @IttyBrittyGirlGamer LessPop re-added the edit for you, so no need to do anything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like an error on the part of the person rejecting the edit.

I don't see anything wrong with the use of that tag.